# maintaining continuous count in php

Tags: php

I have a small problem maintain a count for the position. i have written a function function that will select all the users within a page and positions them in the order.

Eg:
Mike Position 1
Steve Postion 2..............
....
Jacob Position 30

but the problem that i have when i move to the second page, the count is started from first
Eg: Jenny should be number 31 but the list goes,

Jenny Position 1 
Tanya Position 2.......

Below is my function

```
function nrk($duty,$page,$position)
{
    $url="http://www.test.com/people.php?q=$duty&start=$page";

    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);


        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($result);

        $xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
        $elements = $xpath->evaluate("//div");
        foreach ($elements as $element)
        {
            $name  = $element->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $position=$position+1;
            echo $name." Position:".$position."<br>";
        }   
            return $position;
    }
```

Below is the for loop where i try to loop thru the page count

```
for ($page=0;$page<=$pageNumb;$page=$page + 10)
        {
            nrk($duty,$page,$position);
        }
```

I dont want to maintain a array key value in the for each coz i drop certain names...

Answer (score 1):

```
$position = $position + ($page - 1) * $count_per_page; 
//In your case $count_per_page == 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass as a paremeter of the second page an offset, let's say 30. So you position will be `position+offset+1`

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the value of `position` in the function `nrk` and returning the changed value which is not being assigned back to `position` in the loop. So you need to do:

```
$position = nrk($duty,$page,$position);
```

or you can avoid returning the modified value and pass the variable `position` by reference.

Comment: pass-by-reference has been deprecated :(  $position = nrk($duty,$page,$position); doesn't seem to e working.....

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of question is correct, then you need to pass $position variable by a reference, like:

```
for ($page=0;$page<=$pageNumb;$page=$page + 10)
        {
            nrk($duty,$page,&$position);
        }
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but it has been deprecated..
  Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Or you can store the counter in a session variable so that is retrievable from any point of the site.